# Remove extra unwanted lines (columns) at the bottom of the table with tabular

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, addlines

I want to input an external text in a table but I get extra unwanted lines (columns) at the bottom of the table with tabular, I can I remove those?

[image]

Here is the script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{| p{0.5cm} |p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
\input{sample.txt}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the input file:

```
title&title a&title b&title c \\\hline
a&b&c&d\\\hline
a&b&c&d \\\hline
a&b&c&d \\\hline
```

Comment: it comes from the end of file handling, It is possible to avoid this but quite delicate it's much easier if you can put the `\end{tabular}` into the file being input

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `\@@input` primitive instead of `\input` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\let\PlainInput=\@@input
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{625352.txt}
  title & title a & title b & title c \\ \hline
  a     & b       & c       & d \\ \hline
  a     & b       & c       & d \\ \hline
  a     & b       & c       & d \\ \hline
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Using \verb!\input! macro:

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \input{625352.txt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

Using \verb!\@@input! primitive:

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \PlainInput{625352.txt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works, but also requires modifying the file.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test7}
\def\foo{title&title a&title b&title c \\\hline
a&b&c&d\\\hline
a&b&c&d \\\hline
a&b&c&d \\\hline}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \input{test7}
    \begin{tabular}{| p{0.5cm} |p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}|}
\hline
\foo
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```